# Stripe API - Migrating cards to paymentMethods

Tags: stripe-payments

I'm migrating my API from [charges API to Intent API](https://stripe.com/docs/payments/payment-intents/migration#api-version)

Everything is working, but my users have saved cards in the system, which they can choose to pay with. 
These cards are saved in the DB with a stripe card id `card_xxxx`. In Intents this is no longer valid, instead there is `pm_xxx` (payment_method_id).

My question is how do I migrate my existing cards, and get a `payment_method_id` from a `card.id` in order to perform the intent call

In the [docs](https://stripe.com/docs/payments/payment-intents/migration#saved-cards) they mention:

> When paying with a previously saved payment method, you must specify
>   both the ID of the Customer and the ID of the previously saved Card,
>   Source, or PaymentMethod. Previously, the default source on the
>   customer is used if one was not provided. You must now explicitly pass
>   in the desired payment method.

Apparently you can make the same call to `stripe.paymentIntents.create({payment_method: id})` where `id` can be either `pm_xxx` or `card_xxx`.

But will that work in the long run? Do I need to transfer all my `card_xxx` to `pm_xx` in order to be SCA compliant?

Answer (score 2):

After speaking to stripe support - this is their response:

> It isn't possible to migrate card objects to payment methods objects,
>   however our API is backwards compatible, so wherever you see the
>   attribute PaymentMethod in our API reference, you can pass the card
>   object ID instead[2].